# Mobile Advertising (iOS): How can you display targeted ads to a targeted/niche app userbase?

Tags: ios, mobile, ads

I have an application that is very niche and targeted in it's core userbase.

For example sake, leaving the actual application out of the conversation, let's say it's 10 years ago and DVD's are still popular. Let's say we have an iOS app that is all about movie's. Let's say from the application, we have really detailed data on all our users. Such as user10854 has viewed stories related to Arnold Schwarzenegger 313 times, Al Pacino 271 times, and Will Smith 87 times.

I would like to take advantage of this knowledge/data and provide the keywords "Arnold Schwarzenegger" and "Al Pacino" with the intention of serving up a more applicable advertisement. Perhaps an advertisement to buy a copy of The Terminator or The Godfather Trilogy.

Are serving up extremely detailed advertisements like this a pipe dream in my head? (This will be the first time I work with a mobile advertising network).

I also want to serve the up ads as Native ads. My application is a feed, and I'd like to include them as part of the feed to look as unobtrusive as possible.

Does anything like this exist, or is mobile advertising simply not that detailed? Is an advertisement about "movies in general" the most detailed I could hope for vs an add for "play hello kitty island adventure on iOS".

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to provide your own ads (sourced elsewhere), then the logic for displaying them can be as complex as you're willing to make it. If your ads have categories/labels, you can just build up rule sets based on the user metadata to determine which ads will work best (plenty of online ad systems do similar thing based on cookies and so on, Amazon does this heaps).